# How can I use VBA to control the order of elements in an Excel Pivot Table Field List?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a pivot table, which is intended to summarize my data at two different levels of aggregation depending on selections the user has made.

In its original state, here are the feild lists for my pivot table:
[image]

When the user changes certain settings, the following code hides IndexA from the field list:

```
Sheets("test").PivotTables("test").PivotFields("IndexA").Orientation = xlHidden
```

And when the changes are reversed, the following code makes IndexA visible again:

```
Sheets("test").PivotTables("test").PivotFields("IndexA").Orientation = xlRowField
```

The resulting field list now looks like this, with a modified ordering of the elements of the field list:
[image]

Note that in the ROWS field list, IndexA is now at the bottom as opposed to at the top, which destroys the consistency and readability of my report.

My question is.. is there a way to control the ordering of the pivot field list through VBA? or an alternative way to acheive the same result I am looking for? (turning on and off a certain item in the field list and having the order preserved)

I appreciate any help/advice anyone can provide on this topic.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn254297.aspx adddatafield, addfield perhaps? Take a look at the object model and see if you can find out if it's possible. You might have to delete all the fields then add them back in the order you want them instead of reordering them.

Comment: I did try deleting all fields and re-adding, but all of those extra operations made my macros take far too long to run. I implemented the answer below from Scott Holtzman and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code to set the position:

```
With Sheets("test").PivotTables("test").PivotFields("IndexA")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

For future reference, I found this by using the macro recorder and doing it manually, since I could not remember the syntax off the top of my head. Just pointing it out because recording manual actions can come in **very** handy for finding syntax :)

Comment: Thanks Scott! This works well.

It's good to remind myself to always try the macro recorder when in doubt..